# Application Insights page view durration includes incorrect details

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

When examining the browser performance section of Application Insights, I noticed some very high durations under the requests section.  Upon drilling into the sample, I found that the end-to-end transaction details had captured not only the initial page load, but several ajax requests generated by the user after the page had already loaded.  The problem is that I need to know my average page load times but Application Insights is including data that has nothing to do with the initial load of the page.

Everything below the yellow line is generated by normal use and not from the page load.
[image: end-to-end transaction details]

**Question 1a: Is there a way to stop Application Insights from reporting these ajax calls as part of the page load?**  I still need to measure the ajax calls but I don't want them included in the page load time since they had nothing to do with the initial render of the page.

My initialization of application insights takes place in my layout page and looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) {
            function r(config) { t[config] = function () { var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[config].apply(t, i) }) } }
            var t = { config: config }, u = document, e = window, o = 'script', s = u.createElement(o), i, f; for (s.src = config.url || '//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js', u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s), t.cookie = u.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ['Event', 'Exception', 'Metric', 'PageView', 'Trace', 'Ajax']; i.length;)r('track' + i.pop()); return r('setAuthenticatedUserContext'), r('clearAuthenticatedUserContext'), config.disableExceptionTracking || (i = 'onerror', r('_' + i), f = e[i], e[i] = function (config, r, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t['_' + i](config, r, u, e, o), s }), t
        }({
            instrumentationKey: '@Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey'
        });

        window.appInsights = appInsights;

        // Adding telemetry initializer.
        // This is called whenever a new telemetry item
        // is created. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS
        appInsights.queue.push(function () {

            appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope) {
                try {
                    if (envelope.data.baseData.name !== undefined && envelope.data.baseData.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("tatl") > -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    // Don't error out if this fails
                }
            });
        });

        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @:appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext("@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Replace("\\", "\\\\")".replace(/[,;=| ]+/g, "_"));
        }

        appInsights.trackPageView();
    </script>
```

Additional digging lead me to suspect the appInsights.trackPageView() call wasn't behaving properly.  This assumption lead me to lookup the code for trackPageView which took me [here.](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/PageViewManager.ts)
and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/PageViewPerformanceManager.ts)

I could not see anything in the code that cause my issue.  I manually ran the isPerformanceTimingDataReady() call in Chrome's dev tools and it checked out.  I still suspect trackPageView() might be the problem which leads me to

**Question 1b: Is there something other than trackPageView() that I should be using to initialize application insights?**

Comment: As you've already noticed, the durations are reported via a browser-built-in navigator performance API and not through the SDK timing it itself, and so other Ajax calls should not be affecting this duration. Are you aware of any browser scenarios where your ajax calls are blocking the "pageload" event? Are the longer durations sharing a browser, location, etc in common?


Alternatively, can use the duration argument of `trackPageView(null,null,null,null, 1234)`. You can also time your pageloads manually via `startTrackPage()` and `stopTrackPage()`

Comment: I'm unfortunately not aware of any situations where the Ajax calls are blocking the pageload.  I added a logger on the pageload event in dev and it fires when it should.  
The longer events share all the same information with top level request
I've thought about switching over to startTrackPage and stopTrackPage but where do I put the second call?  In the page load event?  I also updated the question with some additional details

Comment: One way to troubleshoot this - open dev tools, check what page view load time was and whether you see the same in Application Insights. Would it be possible to try this?